# Can Groovy classes be used as FitNesse fixtures

Tags: groovy, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am learning the FitNesse framework and wondering if fixture code can be written in Groovy. So I made a copy of an example [Decision Table](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.DecisionTable), renamed the original class as `ShouldIBuyMilkJava` and created a Groovy class with same functionality. So my setup is like this:

**wiki test page** (table rows omitted for brevity):

```
|should I buy milk Java                                         |
|cash in wallet|credit card|pints of milk remaining|go to store?|
|0             |no         |0                      |no          |
|10            |no         |0                      |yes         |

|should I buy milk Groovy                                       |
|cash in wallet|credit card|pints of milk remaining|go to store?|
|0             |no         |0                      |no          |
|10            |no         |0                      |yes         |
```

**ShouldIBuyMilkJava.java**:

Same as [here](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.DecisionTable), except that the class is renamed to `ShouldIBuyMilkJava`

**ShouldIBuyMilkGroovy.groovy**:

```
class ShouldIBuyMilkGroovy {
    def dollars
    def pints
    boolean creditCard

    ShouldIBuyMilkGroovy() {

    }

    // the rest is omitted for brevity
```

Both classes are compiled successfully and are located in a folder that is imported as classpath in the test page. The first test passes successfully, but for the second I get an exception `Could not invoke constructor for ShouldIBuyMilkGroovy[0]`.

I've tried removing an empty no-arg constructor from Groovy class - same result.

How can I make Groovy classes work as FitNesse fixtures?

Comment: Did you define the groovy class to be in a package? Do you have an import table that imports that package (i.e. tells FitNesse to look for classes in that package)? Did the 'execution log' give any details? I'm not very knowledgable about groovy but does it need any additional libraries to be on the classpath, are those all added to FitNesse's fixture classpath?

Comment: @FriedHoeben, thanks for a comment :) Yeah, I put both classes (java and groovy) in the same package, which is imported by FitNesse test SetUp page. I've tried adding Groovy libraries to the classpath - no luck. I'll examine execution log more closely today and update y uestion accordingly.

Comment: @FriedHoeben, your recommendation to examine execution log was super helpful, thanks a lot! I've found that classpath for SlimService didn't contain groovy libraries, although I've placed groovy ```!path``` directive on the test setup page. So I moved that ```!path``` to groovy library onto the ```root`` FitNesse page - and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the fix is simple - I had to include `!path` directive pointing at groovy library into FitNesse `root` page, not into the test page.